# Reference number which automatically resets every month

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating reference no **REF-082013-001** (REF-mmyyyy-001) and incrementing the last part for every entry. REF-082013-001 for first record and REF-082013-002 for second and so on.

My Question is How can i reset the last number by php for every new month. Let say September 2013 I want it to be REF-09-2013-001 and auto increment it till the end of September and then in November reset it again.

Is there a ways to do this in php. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

**Update**

Currently **'REF-'.date('m-Y').$maxnumberfromdb** in single column called reference_no and Now thinking to store the **mm-yyyy** ref1 and last **number** in ref2 separately and start ref2 every first day of the month.

Comment: How are you storing assigned reference numbers?

Comment: Nothing yet, i was thinking to store the mm-yyy and last number separately and on first day of each month, start it again.

Comment: what is your storage? MySQL?

Comment: @Wouter Huysentruit Yes, MySQL

Comment: Out of curiosity, what your trying to achive, you can't manage by adding a date column to your table and later with a query group by day and get all the data you need?

Comment: I am trying to have a reference no to be reset every month. I need reference REF-mmyyyy-number and number should start from 1 for each month.

Comment: @Saleem and why can't you do it using `select concat('REF-',date_format(column,'%m%Y'),@curRow := @curRow + 1)` while ordering by insert date? seems like an easier solution to me, and you'll acomplish the same thing. just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably go with a single table, with an AUTO_INCREMENT field to handle the last part of the reference number, and a date/time field to track when it was last reset.

```
    CREATE TABLE track_reference
        ref_number  INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
        last_reset  DATETIME;
```

Then you write a function in PHP to get a new reference number, which (pseudo-code):

```
    if (MONTH(time()) > MONTH(last_reset)) {
       reset ref_number to 0 (use ALTER TABLE);
    }
    select (ref_number) into $variable;
    return 'REF_<month><year>_$variable;
```

}

It's rough, but you get the idea. I'd also have **YEAR** appear before **MONTH** for making sorting by reference number easier later.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my code for reset counter and update last_reset, this is effective for me

<pre>
$date2 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );
        $month_end = strtotime('last day of this month', time());
        $count = $data['sim_tarif_count'];
        $date3=$date2->format('Y-m-d');

        foreach ( $count as $r2 ){
        $counts[] = $r2['count'];
        $last_reset[] = $r2['last_reset'];}

        $paddedNum = sprintf("%04d", $counts[0]);

        $reg_id =  'SEQ'.$date2->format('Ymd').$paddedNum;
        echo " ";
        echo date('j', $month_end); 
        $counter = $counts[0]+1;

//for reset
if($date2->format('Y-m') > $last_reset[0])
{
            $counter = 0;
            $counting_update=$this->docs_model->update_time_counter($counter,$date3);
            echo $counter = 0;
        } else
{
            $counting_update=$this->docs_model->update_time_count($counter);
}
</pre>
```